# Connect to {MACHINENAME} from iPad

Tags: ip-address, ipad, localhost

I have a website in development running under IIS 7.5 on a Windows 7 machine. From my PC, I can browse to the site via:

- http://localhost/mysite
- http://mymachinename/mysite
- http://mymachinename:80/mysite
- http://myipaddress/mysite
- http://myipaddress:80/mysite

I want to browse the site from my iPad to test some functionality on the actual device, but when I browse to any of the ones (mymachinename or myipaddress) as listed above, Safari pops up a message:

> Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding

The iPad is connected to my WiFi network and I can browse regular publicly hosted sites just fine.  I can ping my iPad's IP address (obtained via DHCP) just fine and, using an app, I can ping my PC OK from my iPad.

Could there be firewall issues causing this? Is there any tool I can use to monitor incoming HTTP requests - a Fiddler for incoming request or something to that effect. What, if any, firewall rule could I add to allow this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - always happens once I post a question!

I needed to set the iPad to use a manual proxy that pointed to myipaddress instead of the default (which is don't use a proxy)

Comment: do tell more! i tried that, entered my localhost ip address in server field, still doesnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

I would double check that any other machine (connected via the same method - DHCP over Wifi) from your house can access the server via its IP address.

If they can, I can't help any further as I have never seen this... Unless you are mucking around with mobile development/Webkit redirection etc.

If they can't, I would take a look at your router and make sure that you do not have a setting such as "Wifi isolation", "Network separation" or similar.

This could be a firewall issue. Make sure that your machine has port 80 unblocked (even if it is blocked at the router / you do not want people outside the network to have access).

Answer (score -2):

Another reason for not being able to access or connect to a local server from ipad, ipod, or iphone is Windows Firewall being on. Turning Firrewall Off will simply fix the problem!